# Android HoloGraphLibrary

Tags: android, sqlite

is the first time I use Fragment and I entered the library HoloGraphLibrary and I want to display a set of data taken from the database, but I get error

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.graph, container, false);

    mHelper = new DbHelper(getActivity());
    show();
    return v;
}
private void show(){
    String author;
    int color;
    Float cost;
    SQLiteDatabase db = new DbHelper(getActivity()).getReadableDatabase();
String sql ="SELECT author, color, SUM(cost) FROM Table WHERE cost>0 GROUP BY author";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);

        while (c.moveToNext()){
            author = c.getString(0);
            color = c.getInt(1);
            cost = c.getFloat(2);


        PieGraph pg = (PieGraph)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.piegraph);

        PieSlice slice = new PieSlice();
        slice.setColor(color);
        slice.setValue(cost);
        pg.addSlice(slice);
        }
        c.close();
        db.close();

        pg.setOnSliceClickedListener(new OnSliceClickedListener(){
...
```

Log
At line 54:`pg.addSlice(slice);`

```
01-22 05:13:32.953: E/AndroidRuntime(1056): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 05:13:32.953: E/AndroidRuntime(1056): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-22 05:13:32.953: E/AndroidRuntime(1056):     at main.Graph_eFragment.show
(Graph_eFragment.java:54)
```

Comment: use achartengine library which is best java library for graph

Comment: where is the end of the while loop ? And where do you call the method show() in your Fragment ?

Answer (score 0):

Likely: `pg` is `null`:

```
PieGraph pg = (PieGraph)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.piegraph);
```

`getActivity()` and the stacktrace suggest you're in a fragment but you're trying to access a view in the activity's view hierarchy. The view should be in your fragment, created in `onCreateView()` you're currently in - the fragment view isn't yet attached to the activity.

One way to solve: pass the view reference from `onCreateView`.

Further obvious problems: you've closing the cursor and database in the loop that reads the cursor.